# Meaning of expression " blanket rationale "

Tags: expressions, translation

> I strongly agree with this point, and don't buy the **blanket rationale**
>   that speed trumps everything in a startup.

I couldn't find its meaning anywhere, what does **blanket rationale** mean?

Comment: Just change "rationale" to "statement".  A blanket statement is one that purports to cover all scenarios and contingencies.  The "blanket statement" would be that "speed trumps everything when a startup company is concerned", and by speed, being first to market is probably the intended meaning.  Speed is more important than any other factor, is the assertion.

Comment: I do believe this is not just a simple matter of definition.  It's almost idiomatic.  The correct answer is given below, and would be difficult to glean from a dictionary.

Comment: That's right, just by trying to search this words together throws no-meaning-related results anyware. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A blanket statement is a generalization - something that covers everything, like a metaphorical blanket. There is an implication when using "blanket statement" that it may be an over-generalization.  For example, "Snow is cold" is a fact; "Nobody who lives here can drive safely in the snow" is a blanket statement, and most likely not completely accurate.

A rationale is a justification, a reason to make a decision.  For instance, I might put chains on my tires, and my rationale might be that heavy snowfall is predicted.

So, to put the two ideas together, a blanket rationale is a justification that may be based on an overgeneralization.  In your example, the speaker believes that many startup companies justify decisions based solely on speed, and implies this is a flawed argument.