# meaning explanation of blanket justification

Tags: translation

I want to know what is this. I hope it is correct, but I'm ask you to be sure 
so please help me .
The complete sentence is :

> network invariably fall back on the blanket justification of giving
>   people what they want .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of expression “blanket rationale”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48066/meaning-of-expression-blanket-rationale).

Comment: That is not *The complete sentence* (because it isn't a complete sentence). Please [edit] and give some context.